# Plot graphs from csv file

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, matplotlib

i want to plot a graphs of my csv file data
now i want epoch as x axis and on y axis the label "acc" and "val_acc" is plot i try the following code but it gives blank graph
`

```
x = []
y = []

with open('trainSelfVGG.csv','r') as csvfile:
    plots = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in plots:
        x.append('epoch')
        y.append('acc')

plt.plot(x,y, label='Loaded from file!')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.title('Accuracy VS Val_acc')
plt.legend()
plt.show()`
```

i am new to python please help the data of csv file look like this

```
epoch|  acc|    |   loss      |lr       |val_acc     |val_loss
0   0.712187529 0.923782527 5.00E-05    0.734799922 0.865529358
1   0.746874988 0.845359206 5.00E-05    0.733945608 0.870365739
2   0.739687502 0.853801966 5.00E-05    0.734799922 0.869380653
3   0.734375    0.872551799 5.00E-05    0.734799922 0.818775356
4   0.735000014 0.817328095 5.00E-05    0.744980752 0.782691181
5   0.738125026 0.813450873 5.00E-05    0.743200898 0.756890059
6   0.749842465 0.769637883 5.00E-05    0.746404648 0.761445224
7   0.740312517 0.779146731 5.00E-05    0.750605166 0.74676168
8   0.745937526 0.77233541  5.00E-05    0.738217294 0.754457355
9   0.760239422 0.717389286 5.00E-05    0.756656706 0.719709456
10  0.758437514 0.727203131 5.00E-05    0.753880084 0.766058266
11  0.756562471 0.718854547 5.00E-05    0.764060915 0.699205279
12  0.751874983 0.735785842 5.00E-05    0.76099956  0.711962938
13  0.762187481 0.709208548 5.00E-05    0.762850642 0.701643765
14  0.766250014 0.689858377 5.00E-05    0.771037996 0.698576272
15  0.791562498 0.642151952 5.00E-05    0.775665641 0.674562693
16  0.773750007 0.672213078 5.00E-05    0.77153641  0.683691561
17  0.785312474 0.657182395 5.00E-05    0.778015077 0.670122385

18  0.770951509 0.685499191 5.00E-05    0.774384141 0.670817852
19  0.777812481 0.673273861 5.00E-05    0.785134554 0.652816713
20  0.80250001  0.626691639 5.00E-05    0.783141136 0.66740793
21  0.787500024 0.64432466  5.00E-05    0.788053513 0.651966989
22  0.7890625   0.621332884 5.00E-05    0.775096118 0.663884819
23  0.787500024 0.637105942 5.00E-05    0.785775304 0.657734036
24  0.794580996 0.616357446 5.00E-05    0.771749973 0.670413017
25  0.803717732 0.599221408 5.00E-05    0.788195908 0.64291203
26  0.811874986 0.587966204 5.00E-05    0.791186094 0.653984845
27  0.804062486 0.591458261 5.00E-05    0.792538822 0.642165542
28  0.797187507 0.602103412 5.00E-05    0.78812474  0.635053933
29  0.807187498 0.595692158 5.00E-05    0.77474016  0.661368072
30  0.811909258 0.577990949 5.00E-05    0.774526536 0.668637931
31  0.820625007 0.546454251 5.00E-05    0.783212304 0.650670886
32  0.82593751  0.53596288  5.00E-05    0.778655827 0.651631236
33  0.805608094 0.582103312 5.00E-05    0.792823553 0.635468125
34  0.822621286 0.555304945 5.00E-05    0.783924222 0.647240341
35  0.823125005 0.551530778 5.00E-05    0.783141136 0.662788212
```

Comment: Please post sample data as text rather than image.

Comment: the plotting command looks good the issue must be with the reading csv, and if the plot comes out to be empty the reason is the the values were not appended in x,y lists. Try pandas that would make the whole task easy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`df.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('trainSelfVGG.csv')
df[['epoch', 'acc', 'val_acc']].plot(
    x='epoch',
    xlabel='x',
    ylabel='y',
    title='Accuracy VS Val_acc'
)

plt.show()
```

Output

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I want to give a detailed answer so you can understand how you can plot any valid values.

First, import the needed libraries and make a fake dataset:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(1,11)
y = np.random.randn(10)
z = y**2
```

Second, make a figure object:

```
fig_sample, ax_sample = plt.subplots()
```

Here **subplot** is used to have the flexibility to add more plots or you can also use for just one single plot

Then add axes (it is only needed when you want to shift it):

```
ax_sample = fig_sample.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1])
```

Set the label:

```
ax_sample.set_xlabel('x (epochs)')
```

Plot the first value x vs y (or epochs vs acc)

```
ax_sample.plot(x, y, label = 'x-y plot')
```

Add a legend to show which graph is representing what:

```
ax_sample.legend(loc=(.8,.8))
```

Repeat for other plots in the SAME axis:

```
ax_sample.plot(x, z, label = 'x-z plot')
ax_sample.legend(loc=(.8,.8))
```